# Rails: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm creating a very basic rails app (learning tutorial) and can't understand why I'm getting this error. I've tried troubleshooting but to no avail.

My code:

```
<ul class = "nav pull-right">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
  <% end %> 

  <% else %>

    <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <%end%>

</ul>
```

Everything was working fine, until I added the Else statement, but no idea what my error is - I'm sure it's a very minor syntax fix, but your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

there has an error in your code.
You have extra `end` in your code before the `else` starts.
Removing that may solve your problem...

Answer (score 9):

The error in your code, as others have pointed out, is the extra `<% end %>` between your `if` and `else` blocks.

In my opinion, the real solution is to add the following to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

(This will often be the real solution for when you see this error message resulting from syntax issues.)

Comment: this is interesting, I hadn't heard of this gem - I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `<% end %>` just before the `<% else %>`.

The code should be as follows:

```
<ul class = "nav pull-right">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>

  <% else %>

    <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
  <%end%>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd use HAML, this could be the cause:

```
- model_class = Products
  .products-page
```

What will solve? Identation.

```
- model_class = Products
.products-page
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot a `do` in a loop:

```
<% @things.each |thing| %>
```

The correct format is:

```
<% @things.each do |thing| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class = "nav pull-right">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to current_user.full_name, edit_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>  
  <% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
 <%end%>
</ul>
```

It should be like this