# Ruby on Rails : Blocks, Methods, Control Flows not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm a newbie in Ruby on Rails, but I've been coding for quite some time on other platforms as C# etc. Problem I'm facing is: Whenever I tried to do any thing in blocks, methods, or control flows it gives me error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' or '\n' ....append=( def createFormTable );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^ <br>
new.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end ...eze;@output_buffer.append=( end );@output_buffer.safe_append... <br> new.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end ...eze;@output_buffer.append=( end );@output_buffer.safe_append... <br> new.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'<br> 
new.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

**My Code**

```
<div class= "row">

<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :comments %>
    <%= f.text_area :comments %>
<%= end %>

</div>
```

No matter I try the above code or just simple condition/method writing as this:

```
<%= if 1==1 %>

<%= else %>

<%= end %>
```

or this :

```
<%= def createFormTable %>
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <%= end %>
<%= end %>
```

**Solutions Tried**

[Rails: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081872/rails-syntax-error-unexpected-keyword-ensure-expecting-end)

[rails: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686411/rails-syntax-error-unexpected-keyword-ensure-expecting-end-of-input)

```
group :development do
 gem 'better_errors'
end
```

Got above code from one of the answers. Please direct me to what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `<%= ... %>` and `<% ... %>`?

Comment: No. not yet. I'm following a tutorial.

Comment: That's a bad tutorial.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some.?

Comment: Also, should I replace mine <%= ... %> with this <%...%> ?

Comment: Yeah I can suggest the best tutorial ever about Rails. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html